# Edit Parameter Field Crystal reports with NOT value?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-10

In Crystal Reports, I want to add a `WHERE field <> date` to filter out dates that have a `NULL` value from my database in my report.

I'm using a legacy FoxPro database on the backend which generates an SQL statement from my report, but doesn't appear to have anyway of adding a `WHERE` clause to the generated statement.

When accessing the FoxPro backend directly, dates with psudo-NULL values have a date of `1899-12-30`, but when they are pulled from FoxPro through Crystal they appear as `12/30/99` (which is maybe the same date just displayed in `MM/DD/YY` format).

I noticed that the report had an existing Parameter Field that prompts the user to filter out the original query down to a specific date range.  I tried to add my own in addition to the Parameter Field, but discovered that what I needed with my `WHERE field <> date` is not an available option since there are only 3 types of Field Parameters mainly:

**Discrete**

- Accept single and discrete values.

**Ranged**

- Accept a lower and upper value in order to select everything in this range.

**Discrete and Ranged**

- A combination of the two above

None of these appear able to filter the results of the query using a `WHERE NOT` type of clause, is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Is the data going to be displayed within a table? If so, I believe that you can do a filter on which rows are displayed that would match this.

Comment: Yes it's going to be displayed in a table in the detail, is that what you mean?

Comment: If all you want to do is exclude NULL dates, you'll want to use the select expert rather than a parameter.  A parameter is used to give the end-user options to choose from, and the select expert is a filter on the source data.  It has a lot of options, including writing a custom formula to filter the data.

Comment: What @EvilBob22 said. You'll need to add something like `{table.field} <> date(1899,12,30)` to your report's selection formula.

Comment: Yes. If my memory of Crystal serves me, you should be able to open the table's properties by right clicking on the table or grouping and adding a visibility setting or filter on the actual detail. Sorry about the lack of specifics, I don't have a copy of Crystal in front of me to give you more details. However, what EvilBob said should work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I really needed to do was add some criteria to the `WHERE` clause of the SQL statement, simple enough in an SQL client, but when you're doing this in Crystal Reports v10 it's a bit difficult to find, unless you know what you are looking for...

So what I needed to do was:

1. Select the field to filter by in the report (in the `Details` section)
2. Click the `Select Expert` [image: The select Expert Button in the Experts toolbar]  button on the `Experts` toolbar.
3. In the `Select Expert` dialog the name of your field should appear in a tab.
4. Below you can select the `WHERE` criteria used to filter the records.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your record-selection formula:

```
// remove actual nulls
AND Not(Isnull({table.date_field})) 
// remove old dates 
AND {table.field} <> date(1899,12,30) 
// remove dates not in select parameter value
AND {table.field} IN {@date_parameter}
```

Comment: Where is the record-selection formula?  On the side bar?  Under formulas?  How do I tell which one is the record selection formula?

Comment: There's actually a little green check mark next to one of the fields in `Field Explorer->Fields->Database Fields->p_active` and when I look at the SQL statement that is generated by Crystal Reports, it has a NOT condition.  How do I access that?